# How to cast pointers in Zig

Tags: zig

I'm trying to rewrite a program in Zig, but I don't know how to use pointer cast. I tried to use `@as`, but apparently that's wrong.

```
fn framebufferResizeCallback(window: ?*cInclude.GLFWwindow, _: c_int, _: c_int) callconv(.C) void {
    var app = @as(*HelloTriangleApplication, cInclude.glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window));
    app.framebufferResized = true;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

[`@as`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#as) is for type coercion. To do a pointer cast, you need to use [`@ptrCast`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#ptrCast). For example:

```
var app: *HelloTriangleApplication = @ptrCast(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(the_window));
```

or

```
var app = @as(*HelloTriangleApplication, @ptrCast(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(the_window)));
```