# Error when using @ptrCast in Zig: "expected 1 argument, found 2"

Tags: pointers, compiler-errors, casting, zig

I'm trying to convert a pointer of type [*]const u8 to [*c]u8 in Zig using the @ptrCast function. However, I'm encountering an error that says "expected 1 argument, found 2" when trying to compile my code.
Here's the relevant snippet from my code:

```c
mp3.track = @ptrCast([*c]u8, track.ptr);
```

I've tried different ways of using @ptrCast, but I keep getting the same error. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Link to the complete code on[Github](https://github.com/alvarorichard/CSoundWave.git)

I was attempting to convert a pointer of type [*]const u8 to [*c]u8 in Zig using the @ptrCast function. I expected the conversion to go smoothly since I'm providing the correct types to the function.
I was hoping that track.ptr would be successfully converted to a mutable pointer and assigned to mp3.track. However, when trying to compile my code, I received an error saying "expected 1 argument, found 2". This was unexpected as I'm using the @ptrCast function according to the documentation.

Comment: Or this: [How to cast pointers in Zig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77168241/how-to-cast-pointers-in-zig)

Comment: Also [Convert i32 into f32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75171967/convert-i32-into-f32)